# Windows 10 - Anaconda 2020.02 - GTK installation fails, gdk-pixbuf

Tags: python, anaconda, gtk, pygtk

Using the solution from:

[Ubuntu - Anaconda 2020.02 - Namespace Gtk not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778993/ubuntu-anaconda-2020-02-namespace-gtk-not-available)

and trying this on a Windows 10 system (again, Anaconda 2020.02) a different problem appeared.

An error box pops up, titled 'gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.exe - Entry Point Not Found', with the text: The procedure entry point libiconv_set_relocation_prefix could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\Library\bin\glib-2.0.0.dll

The text on the console shows up as 'An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::gdk-pixbuf-2.38.2-h67ea0bb_3'

Not too sure what is going on, again.   It would seem that Anaconda thinks these are OK:

https://anaconda.org/search?q=gtk3

https://anaconda.org/search?q=gdk-pixbuf

Installation of gdk-pixbuf seems to be the sticking point, as that fails to install.

Trying to install with 'conda install -c conda-forge gtk3=3.24.14=ZZZZZZZZ' and ZZZZZZZZ are the two different builds yields the same error.

Additional information:

A clean install of Anaconda, with no updates, only:

conda install -c conda-forge gtk3

... still yields problems (lots and lots of conflicts), and the original answer (to install glib) did not consistently solve the problem.